# Linux gateway / DNAT: restrict to certain interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I have various machines with a number of network interfaces:

- eth0: a local LAN
- eth1: sometimes used for the connection to the Internet gateway
- ppp0: Modem uplink as an alternative to eth1
- tun0: OpenVPN tunnel

I want to enable the `tun0` to access the local LAN `eth0`, which is easy with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

However, how can I **disallow** packets coming in from `eth1` or `ppp0` to be routed to eth0 and instead **only** allow `tun0` to use the machine as a gateway?

Do I need to mark these packets using some iptable rules so that I can restrict the MASQUERADE rule to only these packets? Sample iptables configuration greatly appreciated.

*Debian Linux 6 on i386; the `eth0` subnet varies depending on the machine*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://syrlug.org/contrib/ipmasq.html

Section 4.3 should help you out.

With that many interfaces you are going to need some FORWARDING rules.  That way you can specify what get's forwarded and to where.

Check out the link I posted and read up a little on it.  It can get fairly complicated but that section 4.3 has some good info for what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Great! That `FORWARD` chain hint was what I needed.